# How to get notify when a user mention page?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I just started to make Facebook page bot with Facebook Graph Webhooks/APIs

I'm finding a way to receive notifications, including mentioner_id and post_url, when someone mention my page in any posts.

I have tried searching for mentions in app permissions / page subscriptions
I also searched it up and found this one:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/reference/page/#mention

But still no luck...

This is what my page subscription fields looks like:
[image: page subscriptions]

Comment: All info you *can* get, is listed right there.

Comment: @CBroe it said "Full list of page profile fields you can subscribe to.", but I don't see the "mention" field on page subscriptions, I have updated the question with the image.

Comment: Have you tired using the subscriptions edge? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/subscriptions-edge

Comment: @CBroe thanks, that's really help a lot, finally found it but does not work as expected